# ORACLE SQL - sum based on previous row data

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I have a table that looks like this:

| tran_date | tran_num | tran_type | tran_status | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2/12/2021 | 74 | SG | N | 1461 |
| 9/1/2021 | 357 | SG4 | N | 2058 |
| 10/27/2021 | 46 | SG4 | Y | -2058 |
| 10/27/2021 | 47 | SG | N | 2058 |

I would like to identify rows that have negative amounts and sum to previous row to 0, if ordered by tran_date and tran_num.

Expected output:

| tran_date | tran_num | tran_type | tran_status | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2/12/2021 | 74 | SG | N | 1461 |
| 10/27/2021 | 46 | SG4 | Y | 0 |
| 10/27/2021 | 47 | SG | N | 2058 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a lag function in sub-query and then calculating the amount like this:

```
select x.tran_date,x.tran_num, x.tran_type, x.tran_status,
case 
    when x.amount<0 then x.amount + x.lag_win
    else x.amount
end amount
from 
(
select tt.*, 
       lag(amount,1) over (order by tran_date,tran_num) lag_win,
       abs(tt.amount)+lead (amount,1,1) over (order by tran_date,tran_num) pseudo_col
from tran_table tt
)x
where pseudo_col!=0
```

RESULT:

```
12.02.2021  74  SG  N   1461
27.10.2021  46  SG4 Y   0
27.10.2021  47  SG  N   2058
```